# Mulesoft Salesforce to CSV

Tags: file, csv, salesforce, mule

I am revising the question for more clarity. I am trying to import Salesforce contact data to a CSV File.

my Config XML is as below:

```
       <sfdc:connection-pooling-profile initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ONE" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW"/>
</sfdc:config>
<file:connector name="File" writeToDirectory="C:\Users\anataraj\Desktop\Mulesoft Fileconversion\Files" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<file:connector name="File1" writeToDirectory="C:\Users\anataraj\Desktop\Mulesoft Fileconversion\Files" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<file:connector name="File2" writeToDirectory="C:\Users\anataraj\Desktop\Mulesoft Fileconversion" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<data-mapper:config name="XML_To_CSV" transformationGraphPath="xml_to_csv.grf" doc:name="XML_To_CSV"/>
<flow name="testapp2Flow1" doc:name="testapp2Flow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <sfdc:query config-ref="Salesforce1" query="SELECT FirstName,LastName from Contact limit 5" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="XML_To_CSV" doc:name="XML To CSV"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\anataraj\Desktop\Mulesoft Fileconversion" connector-ref="File2" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

The Output get in my file & Logger is of format:

```
"[FirstName, Kyle]",""        
"[Id]",""        
"[LastName, Swenson]",""        
"[type, Contact]",""
```

What I need is in the format:

Kyle,Swenson
Antony,Barker
Rich,Gilbertson

AM i doing wrong in the way i am mapping. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot see your mapping to comment. Try posting a screenshot of your mapping.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I am not able post the screenshot see if you can help: below is the XML i am trying to convert to CSV. How should the data transformer mapping should be <list>
  <map>
    <entry>
      <string>FirstName</string>
      <string>Kyle</string>
    </entry>
     <entry>
      <string>type</string>
      <string>Contact</string>
    </entry>
  </map>
  </list>

Comment: I should have used a data mapper to convert collection to CSV instead of using other connectors. That resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you could have also used Transform message with below config set.

%output application/csv separator=";", header=false